# INotifyPropertyChanged binding selected checkboxes in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to rewrite my CheckBoxList from Code Behind to MVVM pattern in WPF C#. The thing is that now I have a problem to get all selected checkboxes. I have implemented  INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Project is building correctly, when I set the break point I can notice that I received always false value for my checkboxes, even if they are selected. I assume that maybe I did something wrong with data binding. Please, does anybody can help? I am totally newbie in MVVM.

**INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation**

```
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string strPropertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(strPropertyName));
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
 public class SharedModel : ObservableObject
    {

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Method { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
   class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
                private bool _fIsSelected;

                public bool IsSelected
                {
                    get => _fIsSelected;
                    set
                    {
                        _fIsSelected = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                    }
                }

        public ObservableCollection<SharedModel> List { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SharedModel>
        {
            new SharedModel
            {
                Name = "A1",
                Method = Test(),
            },
            new SharedModel
            {
                Name = "A2",
                Method = TestOne()
            }
};

        public string GetSelectedCheckboxes()
        {
             var command =
                    from item in List
                    where item.IsSelected
                    select item.Method;
          return string.Join("\r&", new NewList<string>(command).ToArray());
        }
```

Checkboxlist in XAML

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,769,510">
            <ListBox Name="ListBox"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,133,590,470" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    MinWidth="170" MaxWidth="170"
                                    Margin="0,0, 0, 0" >
                            <CheckBox x:Name="TestCheckbox"
                                      Tag="{Binding Method}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Content="{Binding Name}"
                                Margin="5,0, 15, 0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

**Test View**

```
public partial class TestView : UserControl
{

    public TestView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    }
```

Comment: `SharedModel` inherits `ObservableObject`, but does not bother to actually call the `OnPropertyChanged()` method. So changes to `IsSelected` are never observed. See marked duplicate for basics on _correctly_ implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Although what you say is totally correct, I do not think that this is the actual problem here. If I understand correctly, the changes from the UI are not reflected in the ViewModel as expected, not the other way round. And the UI changes *should* be reflected in the ViewModel, even without a `OnPropertyChanged()` in the setter, right? And actually, using the posted code (with some corrected bracketing) I see the UI changes reflected in the `TestViewModel` using Snoop. So the  error must be somewhere else, I guess...

Comment: @MaSiMan: I agree that the code above works. So, I suppose the question could instead of closed as lacking a [mcve]. But, binding isn't rocket science. It always comes down to: implementing property-change notifications, and making sure the data context is what you expect. The marked duplicate does address that. If the OP feels otherwise, they can edit the question to provide a [mcve] that reproduces their problem in a way not addressed by addressing the usual binding problems (I doubt they'll be able to, but more power to them if they can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding collections, you need 3 kinds of Change Notification:

- Notificaiton if Elements are added or removed from the collection. That is the **only** thing `ObservableCollection<T>` takes care off
- Change Notification on the property exposing the Collection. It can often be nesseary to repalce the entire collection with a new Instance. It would be the proeprty 'List' in your code, but technically taht should not compile as list is a very common class.
- Change Notification on every property of the type T you hold in that Collection. That would be SharedModel in your case.

Your indentation is somewaht messed up, so I have some issues parsing the code you posted.